# PHP: Delete multiple lines from CSV

Tags: php, csv

I would like to delete multiple lines from a CSV file.

I have an array (called `$manual`) setup:

```
Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => B
    [2] => C
    ...
```

My CSV looks like this:

```
A;3h2jhkj
B;ewrwer
C;fsfsdf
D;adsfsdf
E;sdfet
F;35435345f
```

My code to delete the lines are (not working):

```
foreach ($manual as $filename) {
        $table = fopen('logs/error.log','r');
        $temp_table = fopen('logs/error_temp.log','wa+');

        while (($data = fgetcsv($table, 2048, ";")) !== FALSE) {
            if($data[0] == $filename){
                continue;
            }
            fputcsv($temp_table,$data);
        }
        fclose($table);
        fclose($temp_table);
        //$done = "YES";
    }
```

I realise *why* it's not working but can't get it to work.

What I want is all lines in the CSV that have a first column matching a value in the array to be deleted so the resulting CSV file from the above would yield:

```
D;adsfsdf
E;sdfet
F;35435345f
```

Comment: matching (exect) something in the array, will be `in_array`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to iterate `$manual`, just check if value in the `$manual`.

```php
$table = fopen('logs/error.log','r');
$temp_table = fopen('logs/error_temp.log','wa+');

while (($data = fgetcsv($table, 2048, ";")) !== FALSE) {
    if(in_array($data[0], $manual, true)){
        continue;
    }
    fputcsv($temp_table,$data);
}
fclose($table);
fclose($temp_table);
```

Comment: Thanks - I wouldn't have to negate it would I as I am saying if it was in the array then I don't want it...

Comment: I miss that. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks - when reading my question out I sorted but thanks for the reply